# Confusion in looping a Python class

Tags: python, class, loops, debugging, while-loop

Sorry if I don't do this correctly, I am new here. I am trying to make it so that raw_input loops through saving the value of self.x every time so that it asks "r or l"? Whenever you click enter, then raise or lower self.x but I'm not sure how to. If someone could check my work, that would mean a lot. Thank you.

```
q = raw_input("r or l: ")
class game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
    def raise_n(self):
        self.x += 1
        return self.x
    def lower_n(self):
        self.x -= 1
        return self.x
    def main():
        g = game()
        while q == "r":
        print g.raise_n()
        break
    while q == "l":
        print g.lower_n()
        break
main()
```

I also tried this, but it didn't save the value of self.x even if I tried to call main() again.

```
q = raw_input("r or l: ")
class game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
    def raise_n(self):
        self.x += 1
        return self.x
    def lower_n(self):
        self.x -= 1
        return self.x
def main():
    g = game()
    while q == "r":
        print g.raise_n()
        break
    while q == "l":
        print g.lower_n()
        break
main()
```

Any help would be very useful, thank you!

Comment: What happens? What did you expect to happen? What have you tried?

Comment: `q` is outside of your scope of your function....

Answer (score 0):

Your second approach was closer to a valid solution. There are several approaches, and below I show you one, without introducing too many changes. Basically:

- The main() function is executed in an endless loop. Change the True condition if you want to change the stop condition.
- The question is asked and evaluated every time it enters the main() function. Afterwards, it checks if it has to run the *raise_n()* or *lower_n()* methods.

The code:

```
class game():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
    def raise_n(self):
        self.x += 1
        return self.x
    def lower_n(self):
        self.x -= 1
        return self.x

def main():
    q = raw_input("r or l: ")        
    if q == "r":
        print g.raise_n()            
    if q == "l":
        print g.lower_n()  

g = game()
while True:
    main()
```

---

**EDIT:** In order to put as condition for the while loop to iterate a determinated number of times, a constant can be succesively increased and check if it has reached the desired limit:

```
#... Copy previous code here
g = game()
iterations_limit = 10    #Substitute 10 by any positive integer
while k > iterations_limit:
    k += 1    #Increase variable k 
    main()
```

Comment: I don't understand...what would I replace the while loop with? I'm trying to make it repeat after the input is shown (+1 or -1) so that the number can be raised again. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Luke If you don't change the True condition, it will loop indefinitely, and you will only stop it with a user interrupt (e.g. pressing Ctrl + C). If this is the case, you will not be able to get a result at the end. So, you can set up a condition. For example, you can ask the user in every loop if he wants to continue, or you can stablish as well a defined number of iterations

Comment: How would I establish a number of iterations though? The only way I can think of doing this would be using "break" but that didn't work. Sorry about so many questions, I'm new to python.